# Jenkins Transitive Dependency between Global Pipeline Libraries

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

My setup includes 2 Jenkins pipeline libraries, e.g. `lib_generic` and `lib_specialized`, where the second one depends on the first one (will call classes and global vars from the first one).

I have to write my `Jenkinsfile` with the `@library` header that includes both:

`@Library(['lib_generic', 'lib_specialized']) _`
or
`@Library(['lib_generic@v1', 'lib_specialized@v2']) _`

In other words, the Jenkinsfile has to declare the transitive dependencies of the pipeline libraries it uses. I would like to hide that implementation detail.

Ideally, I would like my second library itself to specify its dependency on the library `lib_generic`, and then have the `Jenkinsfile` only declare the library `lib_specialized`.

`@Library(['lib_specialized@v2']) _`

**Is there a known way to do this?**

I would like to add a couple comments:

1. I realize that what I'm asking for, forces me to choose the version of the first library explicitly in the second one, OR delegate to the Global settings, so I probably won't be able to overwrite anything in the `Jenkinsfile`. I am okay with that (it's an implementation detail!).
2. I could use "Load implicitly" for the first library when defining it in the Global Settings. But again, seems like an implementation detail.
3. The [dynamic library loading feature](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically) should be possible, but this seems impractical to me as I would need to declare and import the library over and over in all Classes and global var for the second library. Unless there is a better way?

Comment: That question attracted very little interest. I would take suggestions for making it more engaging...